# PyGTK how to pass a Liststore row value to another class in another python file

Tags: python, gtk, glade

In Glade, I created a `Liststore` that shows me a list of people. When I click on a line, then the line number is inserted into the `self.radek_k_editaci` variable in the list_list method. It's alright.
However, I can't figure out how to use this value in another python file with a different class. I just can't get the value of this variable in another class in a single python file.

```py
from class_database import *
from gi.repository import Gtk
import gi
import os
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from class_database import Database

class Handler:
    def onDestroy(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def list_seznam(self, listseznam):
        (model, pathlist) = listseznam.get_selected_rows()
        for path in pathlist:
            tree_iter = model.get_iter(path)

            #need value of below variable anywhere else  
            self.radek_k_editaci = model.get_value(tree_iter,0)

handler = Handler()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    database = Database()
    builder = Gtk.Builder()
    builder.add_from_file("list.glade")
    seznam = database.vypis_vseho()
    model = builder.get_object("liststore")
    builder.connect_signals(Handler())
    model.clear()
    for i in range(len(seznam)):
        model.append(seznam[i])
    window = builder.get_object("win_list")
    window.show_all()

    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Please translate the title of your question to English.

Comment: @Rodrigo as it's only the title, I imagine this is an honest mistake, let's give OP a chance to fix it ;)

Comment: Create a variable in that other class called `self.radek_k_editaci`. Create a method (function) in that other class called `set_radek_k_editaci()` that sets the value of `self.radek_k_editaci` to whatever is passed to it as an argument. Whenever you want to set the other class's variable, call `set_radek_k_editaci()` with value that you want to set `self.radek_k_editaci` to.